# Replacing illegal character in fileName

Tags: java, regex, replace

In Java, I've a File-Name-String. There I want to replace all illegal Characters with '_', but not `a-z`, `0-9`, `-`,`.` and `_`

I tried following code: But this did not worked!

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("[\\W][^\\.][^-][^_]", "_");
```

Comment: Since the title is more general that the actual question, my solution to this problem was to use `filename = URLEncoder(fileName, "UTF-8")` for filenames. The result of this operation is always a valid filename. This also allows to get the original filename characters using `URLDecoder` on the filename

Comment: There is no guaranty that resulting filename is always valid. * is not a valid character.

Comment: filename = URLEncoder(fileName.replaceAll("\\\*","%2A"), "UTF-8");

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You need to replace everything but `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]`. 
The `^` within the brackets stands for "NOT".

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-]", "_");
```

Comment: Yes but then there is removed '.' '_' and '-'

This characters shouldn't be removed!

Comment: @bbholzbb I don't think so.

Comment: I know the scope has not been well defined but there are many more valid characters than just 0-9 and a-z. What about foreign languages? For Windows see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: What about other UTF-8 characters? I mean other languages?

Comment: That shouldn't work... `.` (period) stands for "any character"... does it not? It should probably be escaped such as `"[^a-zA-Z0-9\\.-]"`... you might also want to add a `+` in order to "pack together" several forbidden characters: `"[^a-zA-Z0-9\\.-]+"` ...

Comment: You really should test your code before posting it... both `.` and `-` has to be escaped! I managed to get this regex to work: `[^a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]`

Comment: what about space ? space is allowed but I think it will be replaced by under_score.

Comment: @Erk "In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (\\), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-). The usual metacharacters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash. To search for a star or plus, use [+*]. Your regex will work fine if you escape the regular metacharacters inside a character class, but doing so significantly reduces readability." [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: @Nimnio: I can't be sure this much time later, but I am fairly certain I tested that regex in Java. (And I see now the answer was updated...)

Comment: Hi @Erk. `someString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]", "_")` works fine on JDK 1.7.0_67. Whoever updated the answer did so needlessly.

Comment: @Erk, I just re-read your earlier comment (May 20) and spotted the problem. You used `[^a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]`. The hyphen can be included right after the opening bracket, or right before the closing bracket, or right after the negating caret; otherwise, it's treated as a range specifier, so in your example failing to escape it would result in an error or unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Nimnio: I think the unescaped version of the `-` is a sure fire way to introduce future compilation errors when someone needs to add another character to the regex. I'm usually programming in projects with several people, so I'd escape the `-` to keep the code more changeable. (I have to test the unescaped version of the `.` with regards to if it will replace periods or not).

Comment: @Erk: I have tested that `[^.]` does not replace periods. I understand your point, which is similar to the best-practice that we should use parentheses for single-statement conditionals even though they're not "required", but it is worth correcting the mistaken assumption that ". and - have to be escaped". Character classes are handled very differently than the rest of the regex, and users of them should appreciate the distinction. (Consider that if `.` and `*` were treated as wildcards in character classes, then `[.]`, `[*]`, and `[a-z*.]` would all be equivalent to just `.`.)

Comment: Since when space is illegal? how about "[^\\sa-zA-Z0-9.-]"

Comment: Since there are just a few illegal characters (rest of the unicode characters are ok), isn't it better to just avoid them in the regular expression?

Comment: what about file names of different languages? the OS allow it, but you remove them

Comment: @DavidS I didn't knew brackets made special characters be treated differently, however I did test the code before posting, so it was probably the placement of the `-` that caused the problem. Thanks for the new knowledge! (Oh, and never forget to test code before posting! :))

Comment: `[^-a-zA-Z0-9.]` for those who prefer to avoid redundant escapes. Inside the square brackets, `.` need not be  escaped anywhere, and `-` need not be escaped at the edges of the expression (and `&&` means _intersection_ / _and_).

Answer (score 32):

If you are looking for options on windows platform then you can try below solution to make use of all valid characters other than "\/:*?"<>|" in file name.

```
fileName = fileName.replaceAll("[\\\\/:*?\"<>|]", "_");
```

Comment: You can replace illegal characters with fullwidth counterparts: `／＼＼：＊？＂＜＞｜`

Comment: Sorry, should the regex actually be 4x backslashes instead of 2x? Ex: `"[\\\\/:*?\"<>|]"`

Comment: another set of replacement characters ” ‹ › ⁎ ∕ ⑊ ＼︖ ꞉ ⏐

Answer (score 16):

Keep it simple.

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]", "_");
```

http://ideone.com/TINsr4

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably because there is a similar answer with better (?) explanation.

Comment: Is there any java API available that can takes care of this? due to further compatibility issues. I mean this manual replacement might produce some errors in other environments other than windows.

Comment: @rajper not AFAIK. The simplest thing is to determine the set of all illegal characters on all platforms you want to support, and replace them all.

Answer (score 12):

Even simpler

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("[^\\w.-]", "_");
```

Predefined Character Classes:

- `\w`     A word character: `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`

Answer (score 2):

I know there have been some answers here already, but I would like to point out that I had to alter the given suggestions slightly.

```
filename.matches("^.*[^a-zA-Z0-9._-].*$")
```

This is what I had to use for .matches in Java to get the desired results. I am not sure if this is 100% correct, but this is how it worked for me, it would return true if it encountered any character other than a-z A-Z 0-9 (.) (_) and (-).

I would like to know if there are any flaws with my logic here.

In previous answers I've seen some discussion of what should or should not be escaped. For this example, I've gotten away without escaping anything, but you should escape the (-) minus character to be safe as it will "break" your expression unless it is at the end of the list.
The (.) dot character doesn't have to be escaped within the ([]) Square Braces it would seem, but it will not hurt you if you do escape it.

Please see Java [Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use more than like [A-Za-z0-9], then check [MS Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions), and dont forget to filter out "...Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31,...".