# Replacing caracters that can't used in a windows filename

Tags: java

I'm receiving emails with attachments, later I need to store those attachements to a windows machine, using their original filenames,

Sometimes writing those attachements fails, when they contain special caracters such as '@ # ..' that windows wouldn't allow in a filename,

My question is, if there this an existing method that would validate filenames, remove/replace all caracters a windows os wouldn't allow a filename to have.

Comment: You mean like https://stackoverflow.com/q/15075890/438992 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/1184176/438992?

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm looking for, it seems i haven't used the correct key words to find those questions,

Thank you for your help !